# Jquery date time picker with 2013-05-30 19:02:51.497 format

Tags: javascript, jquery, format, datetimepicker

I am able to bring the jquery calendar with the following code.

```
$( "#startDate, #endDate" ).datetimepicker();
```

this also brings me date picker and time I get  the following format : `10/08/2013 05:23 PM` but I want the selected date to have the following format `2013-05-30 19:02:51.497` how do I do that with jquery?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by using [jquery-ui-datetimepicker-plugin](http://timjames.me/jquery-ui-datetimepicker-plugin)

```
$('#startDate, #endDate')
    .datetimepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss' });
```

Comment: if not there is no need for me to post it here :)

Answer (score 0):

I have followed this

but did not work and working one is

```
$("#startDate, #endDate").datetimepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss'});
```